# prove that $\{Lx:\|x\|\leq 1 \}=\mathbb{C}$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $X$ be a linear normed space over $\mathbb{C}$. If a linear functional $L$ on $X$ is not continuous, prove that $\{Lx:\|x\|\leq 1 \}=\mathbb{C}$

Clearly $\{Lx:\|x\|\leq 1 \}\subseteq \mathbb{C}$. For other inclusion, let $z\in \mathbb{C}$. Since $L$ is not continuous $L$ is not bounded. Hence there is $x_0\in X$ such that $|L(x_0)|> |z|\|x_0\|$. Wanted to show that $L(x_0)=z$ and $\|x_0\|\leq 1$. But I was stuck. Am I in the wrong track? Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Is this meant to be $\{ Lx : \| x \| \leq 1 \text{ and } x \in \mathcal{D}(L) \}$? (Typically unbounded operators/functionals are not considered to be defined everywhere.)

Comment: @Ian What do you mean by $D(L)$? This is all of the question.

Comment: $\mathcal{D}(L)$ is the domain of $L$.

Comment: Yep. $x\in X=D(L)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. Given the inequality, $L(x_0)>|z|\|x_0\|$, you can divide by $\|x_0\|$ on both sides to get $L(x)>|z|$ for a vector $x$ with $\|x\|=1$. Now try modifying $x$ a little further (e.g, by scaling it down) to find a vector which maps to $z$ exactly.

Comment: If $x=\frac{x_0}{||x_0||}$ then $|L(x)|>|z|$ and $||x||=1$. How can I proceed from here now?

Comment: Try multiplying $x$ by a scalar to give a new vector $y$, and see what scalar you would need to multiply by in order for it to come out to the right thing, i.e. to make $L(y)=z$.

Comment: Ok, so if $z=|z|e^{i\alpha}$ and if $L(x)=|L(x)|e^{i\beta}$, then considering $L(e^{i(\alpha - \beta)}x)=e^{i(\alpha - \beta)}L(x)=e^{i(\alpha - \beta)}|L(x)|e^{i\beta}=|L(x)|e^{i\alpha}$. But in order to get the final result we must prove that $|L(x)|=|z|$. Already we have $|L(x)|>|z|$. I don't know how to prove other inequality.

Comment: Instead try multiplying by a general scalar, not necessarily of modulus 1.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B$ be the closed unit ball.

If $LB = \mathbb{C}$ then there is a sequence $x_n \in B$ such that $|Lx_n| > n$. Then ${1 \over n} x_n \to 0$ but $L ({1 \over n} x_n) \not\to 0$, hence $L$ is not continuous.

Suppose $L$ is not continuous. Then there is a sequence $x_n \to 0$ such that $|Lx_n| \ge 1$ for all $n$. Let $y_n = {1 \over \|x_n\|} x_n$, then 
$y_n \in B$ and $|L y_n| \ge {1 \over \|x_n\|}$, in particular, $\lim_{n \to \infty} |L y_n | = \infty$.

By linearity we have $0 \in LB$. Now pick $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ and $n$ such that $|L y_n | \ge |\alpha|$. Let
$z = { \alpha \over L y_n } y_n$, then $z \in B$ and $Lz = \alpha$. Hence $LB = \mathbb{C}$.